# How many current US senators are NOT from political families?

Tags: united-states, democracy, senate, senate-rules

Recently, I've read an interesting [article](https://www.brookings.edu/opinions/political-dynasties-an-american-tradition/) about US political dynasties:

> It is perhaps not very surprising that so many children of politicians go into politics. After all, it’s daddy’s business. Lots of doctors’s children go to medical school.

Let's use definition from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_family):

> A political family (also referred to as political dynasty) is a family in which several members are involved in politics — particularly electoral politics. Members may be related by blood or marriage; often several generations or multiple siblings may be involved.

Note: a political dynasty means any family with two or more people in a elected position.

**Is there any information about how many current senators are NOT from such families?**

Comment: Better, but it’s still unclear how many family members are needed to be a dynasty. Some are clear, your Kennedy’s, Bush’s, and Cheney’s, but there’s a lot of people who would be borderline.

Comment: Are we to count politicians with relatives who are politics-adjacent?  Lobbyists, financiers, organizers, etc?

Comment: @Ryan_L Senator Gillibrand is a good example of that and I put her in a "Borderline" category. I think they really have to be part of the political machine to count, though. Simply being politics-adjacent is too broad a category, I think, if the goal is to see whether political family connections are associated with being elected to office.

Comment: This is a very good question in my mind, but I think we can make it even better if we expand it to include the House and cabinet positions, and maybe Federal judges and state governors.  I mean the same kind of question could be asked of all these positions, may as well put them all in the same question.

Comment: We need a clear definition here of what counts as a political family, e.g. "several". Otherwise it's like "which Presidents *aren't* related?" (to which the answer is none by many of the more common metrics, but not all of the metrics).

Comment: Dynasty implies more than one generation, a hereditary democracy if you like...

Comment: This is Stack Exchange: your question needs to show what research you already did.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As this is the sort of question that would benefit from group research and updating as the Senate changes, here is a wiki answer.  Please update this if you find any senators who have been missed, who are no longer in office, or who have political relatives who have been omitted.

How to define a "dynasty" is unclear.  In the interests of definiteness, this list will include all senators who have/had spouses, parents, children, grandparents, aunts, uncles, and (first) cousins who hold/held an elected position in the United States.  This is admittedly a broader definition than most people would give for a "dynasty", but it allows for a more definite answer.

#### Current senators with relatives in politics

- [Lisa Murkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_Murkowski) (R-AK).  Daughter of [Frank Murkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Murkowski), former US senator & governor of Alaska.
- [John Boozman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Boozman) (R-AR).  Brother of [Fay Boozman](https://encyclopediaofarkansas.net/entries/fay-boozman-12068/), former Arkansas state senator.
- [John Hickenlooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hickenlooper) (D-CO).  Grand-nephew of [Bourke Hickenlooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourke_B._Hickenlooper), former US senator & governor of Iowa.
- [Rand Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_Paul) (R-KY).  Son of [Ron Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Paul), former US Representative from Texas and presidential candidate.
- [Mitt Romney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitt_Romney) (R-UT).  Son of [George Romney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Romney), former governor of Michigan.  [Several other relatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romney_family) involved in politics in other capacities.
- [Maria Cantwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Cantwell), (D-WA). Daughter of [Paul Cantwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Cantwell) who served as a member of the Indiana Senate, as well as the Indianapolis City-County Council, and before that, the Marion County Board of Commissioners.
- [Shelley Moore Capito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelley_Moore_Capito), (R-WV). Daughter of [Arch A. Moore Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_A._Moore_Jr.), who served 3-terms as governor.
- [Joseph Manchin III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Manchin), (D-WV). His father and grandfather were both mayor of Farmington, WV, and his uncle was a member of the West Virginia House of Delegates and later the West Virginia Secretary of State and Treasurer.

### Questionable or Borderline Cases

- [Mark Kelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Kelly), (D-AZ).  Husband of [Gabby Giffords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabby_Giffords), former US Representative from Arizona. Neither of them have family political connections, though, so it's more of a husband-wife team than a dynasty.
- [Kirsten Gillibrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirsten_Gillibrand), (D-NY). While her family, going back to her grandparents, was deeply involved in Democratic party politics, none of them ran for political office themselves.

### Current Senators without relatives in politics

- [Dan Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Sullivan_(U.S._senator)) - (R-AK)
- [Richard Shelby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Shelby) - (R-AL)
- [Tommy Tuberville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Tuberville) - (R-AL)
- [Tom Cotton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Cotton) - (R-AR)
- [Krysten Sinema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrsten_Sinema) - (D-AZ)
- [Dianne Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dianne_Feinstein) - (D-CA)
- [Alex Padilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Padilla) - (D-CA)
- [Ed Markey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Markey) - (D-MA)
- [Elizabeth Warren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Warren) - (D-MA)
- [Chuck Schumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Schumer) - (D-NY)
- [Patty Murray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patty_Murray) - (D-WA)
- [Ted Cruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Cruz) - (R-TX)
- [Tina Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tina_Smith) - (D-MN)

Comment: As of this writing, I have looked through the Wikipedia biographies of the senators alphabetically by state up to Georgia.  I have also added Sens. Paul & Romney as particularly well-known examples.

Comment: +1 - that's brilliant. Though, question deliberately specifies senators that are NOT from families, goal senators can be found by an exclusion

Comment: None of MN or WA's senators come from dynasties, for whoever's working through the list rn

Comment: I might remove Mark Kelly – the fact that his wife ran for office after they got married doesn't make him part of a dynasty. I think the criteria should require at least another generation

Comment: @divibisan:  That's debatable, but you'd have to rule out the Clintons as a political dynasty if you did that.  (Not that either of them are currently in the Senate.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't think that would be that bad – the line of succession is a key part of the meaning of dynasty, and the way that Hilary Clinton entered into politics is, I think, a different kind of thing than someone who's Father (for example) was a Senator.

Comment: What do people think of [Kristen Gillibrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirsten_Gillibrand)? She was definitely born to a political family, but none of them actually ran for office.

Comment: @divibisan:  Maybe include her in the "no relatives in politics" list but with an explanatory note?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I added a "Questionable" category for people to put cases like this in.

Comment: Ted Cruz seems to have no relatives in American politics.  His wikipedia article makes no mention of any cousins.  It lists closer relatives without saying anything about their political careers, which says to me they don't have political careers.

Comment: Note: [This answer is being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5833/wiki-answers-for-changing-information)

Comment: @Ryan_L added that to the answer.